# Not a Valid Password error connecting to Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application used by approximately 10 member team. The data entered by the team in the form is stored in an access database which is stored in a common server. I have not changed the database password from the time of creation. But in the recent times, some of the team members are getting error while saving the data in the database. The error is "Not a valid password".
The same form is being used by all the team members & all connect to the same database but only few are getting this error (only some times but not all the times).

Can any one suggest what might be the possible reasons why the error is happening?

Comment: Access databases aren't thread safe.  Use a real database in this scenario, like sql server express.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response. But unfortunately i don't have access to install sql server & the only database i can use is an access database. :(

Comment: If that is the case (simultaneous access to same `mdb` file by multiple users), then: 1) make sure you connect to database shortly (no `static` connections please) 2) implement file-based synchronization (not sure what is `ldb`, but you can create some file near `mdb`, open it exclusively first, then establish connection, then close connection and close file.. anyone trying to open that file while it is in use will fail -> synchronization).

Comment: @Sintar I will try this option. As of now the connection remains open after an analyst saves the data to the database. I will try the option suggested by you & revert. Thank you